# Shape of $[0,1] / \{ (x,y) \mid x-y=\frac{p}{2^q}, p,q \in \mathbb{Z}\}$

Tags: general-topology, reference-request

Let $R$ be an equivalence relation given by
$$ R = \left\{ (x,y)\ \Big|\ x-y=\frac{p}{2^q}, p,q \in \mathbb{Z}\right\}.$$

What is the topology of $[0,1] / R$? Does this structure collapse to something trivial? What is its Euler characteristic or some other topological properties?

Are there any interesting topologies where zooming in/out doesn't make a difference? For example fractals, $\mathbb{Q}$ or *the* random graph would be some instances, but if you zoom in, you get a *copy* of the structure, what about getting back the structure itself?

Any info or references would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: The topology is the trivial one (the only open sets are the empty set and the full space).

Comment: @Did Does it mean that its fundamental group is trivial too?

Comment: Yes. Hint: What are the continuous functions $[0,1]\to X$ when $X$ has the trivial topology?

Comment: @Did You mean that any function is continuous, so any function $h : [0,1]\times[0,1] \to X$ could be a homotopy and all loops belong into one big class, right?

Comment: Just reading the definitions and applying them.